# Problems defining a DTO and a Repository for a View with JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, view

I want to define a DTO and a Repository for Views using Spring + JPA + Hibernate.

After researching a lot, I try to define my DTO as following:

```
@Table(name = "view_my_table")
public class ViewMyTable {

    @Column
    private String domain;

    @Column
    private String subdomain;

    @Column
    private String usr;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Only setting the *@Table* annotation to the class and the @Column annotation to the columns.

And then I have the associated Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface IViewMyTableRepository extends IRepository<ViewMyTable, ViewMyTable> {

    List<T> findByDomain(String domain);

    List<T> findBySubdomain(String subdomain);

    List<T> findByUsr(String usr);
}
```

All seems ok, but when I started the application I have some errors there:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IViewMyTableRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract List a.b.c.interfaces.IViewMyTableRepository.findByDomain(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract List a.b.c.interfaces.IViewMyTableRepository.findByDomain(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class a.b.c.views.dto.ViewMyTable
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:156)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.<init>(JpaQueryCreator.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaCountQueryCreator.<init>(JpaCountQueryCreator.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.createCreator(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:259)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    ... 72 more
```

I think that something is wrong with the RepositoryFactoryBean, but I don't know what. Anybody knows how to define correctly a View with JPA?

If I define the View as *@Entity* and as *@IdClass* pointing to itself, and include the *@Id* to all the columns, doesn't work when a column has a null value.

Thanks...

Comment: You need `@Entity` else it won't be recognized as a JPA class.

Comment: What is IRepository? Who does implement it? Why does it have ViewMyTable as a generic parameter two times? Why does your hibernate entity have no @Id?

Comment: If I use *@Entity* I need to specify Id, and the easiest way to do that is to set all the columns as Id, what doesn't work when I have nulls. Any other working approach?

Comment: Florian, IRepository is the interface that should be extended in order to Spring create the associated DAO. This interface has 2 parameters: the first one is the Class, and the second is the Class that represents the ID (itself in this case, but I'm not sure that this works). My entity has no ID because it is not a Table, it is a View.